# Java derby sql integer query

Tags: java, sql

Please take a look at my code snippet below.  What I am trying to achieve is querying the database for any results equal to the user input.  It is querying `SDS_NUMBER` column which is an integer column.

When I execute the query it returns the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:  Comparisons between 'INTEGER' and
>   'CHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported.  Types must be comparable.
>   String types must also have matching collation....etc.

I understand that it is saying I am trying to compare an integer to char but I have tried to cast from examples I found on the net but no luck.  Also I tried `parseInt` and using that value in the search but I still can't get it to work.  Please advise what I am doing wrong and excuse my newbies to all of this.

```
     } else if (tmp == "sdsNumber") {
        try {
            Integer sdsNum = Integer.parseInt(val);
            String sql = "SELECT SDS_NUMBER, PRODUCT_NAME, PROPER_SHIPPING_NAME FROM APP.MASTER WHERE SDS_NUMBER = '"+sdsNum+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
```

Master table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE MASTER
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
,   SDS_NUMBER integer UNIQUE
,   PRODUCT_NAME varchar(100)
,   PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION varchar(500)
,   SDS_FILE_PATH varchar(50)
,   USE_STATUS BOOLEAN
,   DATA_UPDATED date
,   PROPER_SHIPPING_NAME varchar(100)
,   SIGNAL_WORD varchar(20)
,   CONSTRAINT MASTER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Don't concatenate parameters, use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote `"'"+sdsNum+"'"` to be a number

Her ara Example by using `preparedStatement`

```
String sql = "SELECT SDS_NUMBER, PRODUCT_NAME, PROPER_SHIPPING_NAME FROM APP.MASTER WHERE SDS_NUMBER = ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, sdsNum);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    int SDS_NUMBER = rs.getInt("SDS_NUMBER");
    String PRODUCT_NAME= rs.getString("PRODUCT_NAME");
    ....

}
```

Comment: So I tried this.  It allows the query to succeed without the exception but will not return any result. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what is going on in the while loop.  I get a compiler error on the String PRODUCT_NAME line for incompatible types (int cant be converted to string). could you clarify what this is doing for me.  Sorry for being such a newbie to this, I am learning but slowly.

Comment: I have changed the rs.getInt to rs.getString and that took care of the compiler error and the program functions.  The table is updated with a blank result set.  Right now the database is in test and I only have one record (SDS_NUMBER int'999').  When I try to test the query by entering 999 into the text field I get no result. Is there a way to command the database to spit out what it is seeing as the query request?  I have the other 2 search methods figured out now but this one is causing me much pain.  any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you attach the database sttucture?

Comment: Iam sorry for my typo  (rs.getInt  it return int and getString return String )

Comment: Alya, being new I'm not sure what you want for the database structure? Like attach the db? And if so how do I do that?

Comment: i just want to see the statements which you write to build your table , `When I try to test the query by entering 999 into the text field ` , so where is the query statement which you used to retrieve the data from the database ??

Comment: Alya, thanks for looking into this for me.  I have edited the original post to show the db construction.  Please let me know if that isnt what you were looking for,

Comment: `When I try to test the query by entering 999 into the text field I get no result` no result mean that you didn't have this value in you db , so make sure first you already have this value

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're wrapping an integer in quotes

```
SDS_NUMBER = '"+sdsNum+"'"
```

probably what you want is

```
SDS_NUMBER = ?
```

and then set the number with your PreparedStatement instead of concatenating strings

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

and

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

```
} else if ("sdsNumber".equals(tmp)) {
```

after I changed the first line to this everything works.  I dont fully understand what difference that made and if someone could shine some light on it, I would appreciate it as I am slowly learning this.